# Page Design Distortion on Navigation Back ListView Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Basically i have the following code on my `ItemTemplate`

```
<Frame BorderColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ColorTwo, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"  BackgroundColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ColorOne, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}" Padding="2" HeightRequest="{Binding Path=LeilaoHeight, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}" CornerRadius="0">
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Spacing="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Image VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="{Binding ProdutoImagem}"  Aspect="AspectFit" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,5,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <!--<RowDefinition Height="*"/>-->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TextName}" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TextColor, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Nome}" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TextColor, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"/>
            <BoxView Color="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ColorTwo, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="1"/>
            <BoxView Color="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ColorTwo, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="1"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TextPrize}" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TextColor, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProdutoNome}" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TextColor, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"/>
            <BoxView Color="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ColorTwo, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="1"/>
            <BoxView Color="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ColorTwo, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="1"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TextMinimumBid}" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TextColor, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding QuantidadePontos}" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TextColor, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"/>
            <!--<Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TextLastBid}"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TextColor, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding UltimoLance}"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TextColor, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"/> -->
            <BoxView Color="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ColorTwo, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="1"/>
            <BoxView Color="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ColorTwo, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="1"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TextExpiration}" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TextColor, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TempoRestante, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  TextColor="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TextColor, Source={x:Reference Name=AuctionListViewXaml}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

which translates to the items in the `ListView` below

[image: NonDistorted]

And whenever i navigate forward to another page, if i press back the entire view gets distorted

This one below is a mild example of distortion, check for the text on the second card in the listview, there are words missing but the underlying layout size stays the same, if the screen is smaller it will cut everything so much more.

[image: Distorted]

Has anyone ever had troubles with this before? It happens on the following cases:
I navigate back from another screen.
The object is added to the list from another list.

I've tried loads of things and it consistently happens on Android, iOS is bug free as far as i know.

Xamarin Forms 3.4.0 the listview I'm using is the syncfusion listview.

Edit: also happening in the xamarin list view

ContentPage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using AppAlice.Localization;
using AppAlice.Models;
using AppAlice.UiModels;
using AppAlice.ViewModels;
using Syncfusion.ListView.XForms;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppAlice.Views
{
    public partial class AuctionListView : ContentPage
    {
        public AuctionListViewModel viewModel;
        MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }

        public double ScreenWidth { get; set; } = App.ScreenWidth;
        public double ScreenHeight { get; set; } = App.ScreenHeight;
        public double LeilaoHeight { get; set; } = App.ScreenWidth / 4;



        public AuctionListView()
        {
            Title = AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString("AuctionListViewTitle");
            BindingContext = viewModel = new AuctionListViewModel();
            LeilaoHeight = App.ScreenWidth / 4;
            InitializeComponent();
            activatedButton.Text = AppResources.Active;
            availableButton.WidthRequest = activatedButton.WidthRequest = ScreenWidth / 2;
            availableButton.Text = AppResources.Available;
            HelloLabel.Text = AppResources.Hello;
            SaldoLabel.Text = AppResources.Balance + ": ";
            //XpLabel.Text = AppResources.PointsInBids;
            AuctionLabel.Text = AppResources.PointsAuction;
        }

        private void availableButton_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            activatedListView.IsVisible = false;
            activatedButton.BackgroundColor = App.ColorThree;
            availableListView.IsVisible = true;
            availableButton.BackgroundColor = App.ColorTwo;


        }

        private void activatedButton_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            availableListView.IsVisible = false;
            availableButton.BackgroundColor = App.ColorThree;
            activatedListView.IsVisible = true;
            activatedButton.BackgroundColor = App.ColorTwo;

        }

        async void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            Leilao leilao = e.Item as Leilao;
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new AuctionPage(leilao)) { BarBackgroundColor = App.ColorTwo, BarTextColor = App.TextColor });

        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            if (viewModel.OnAppearingCommand.CanExecute(null))
                viewModel.OnAppearingCommand.Execute(null);
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            if (viewModel.OnDissappearingCommand.CanExecute(null))
                viewModel.OnDissappearingCommand.Execute(null);
        }


        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            RootPage.NavigateFromMenu((int)MenuItemType.Browse);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Relevant ViewModel Methods:

```
private void OnDisappearing()
{
    Timer.Stop();
}

private async Task OnAppearing()
        {
            AvailableAuctions.Clear();
            ActivatedAuctions.Clear();
            OnPropertyChanged("AvailableAuctions");
            OnPropertyChanged("ActivatedAuctions");
            Timer.Start();
            Timer.Interval = 500; // 0.1 seconds
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Perfil = CallsWrapper.GetUser();
                    Nome = Perfil.Nome;
                    Saldo = Perfil.PontuacaoAtual;
                    Xp = Perfil.PontuacaoHistorico;
                    Imagem = Perfil.Foto.Url;

                    if (CallsWrapper.IsOnline())
                    {
                        LeilaoDtoDataStore leilaoDtoDataStore = new LeilaoDtoDataStore(Perfil.Id);
                        var leiloes = await leilaoDtoDataStore.GetItemsAsync();


                        foreach (var l in leiloes.Where(i => i.MeuUltimoLance == 0)) AvailableAuctions.Add(l);
                        foreach (var l in leiloes.Where(i => i.MeuUltimoLance != 0)) ActivatedAuctions.Add(l);
                        //AvailableAuctions = new ObservableCollection<Leilao>(leiloes.Where(i => i.MeuUltimoLance == 0));
                        //ActivatedAuctions = new ObservableCollection<Leilao>(leiloes.Where(i => i.MeuUltimoLance != 0));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //TODO: TEXTO FALANDO QUE NAO ESTA ONLINE
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    Perfil = new PerfilClienteDto();
                    Nome = Perfil.Nome;
                    Saldo = Perfil.PontuacaoAtual;
                    Xp = Perfil.PontuacaoHistorico;

                }
                finally

                {
                    Timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Perfil");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Nome");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Saldo");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Xp");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Imagem");
                }
            });
        }

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                foreach (Leilao s in ActivatedAuctions)
                {
                    s.Temporizador = getTimeLeft(s.DataEncerramento);
                    if (s.Temporizador.TotalDays > 0)
                    {
                        if (s.Temporizador.TotalDays > 1 && s.Temporizador.TotalDays < 2)
                            s.TempoRestante = string.Format("{0} Dia", (int)s.Temporizador.TotalDays);
                        else
                        {
                            s.TempoRestante = string.Format("{0} Dias", (int)s.Temporizador.TotalDays);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s.TempoRestante = string.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}s", (int)s.Temporizador.TotalHours, s.Temporizador.Minutes, s.Temporizador.Seconds);
                    }
                    s.OnPropertyChanged("TempoRestante");
                }
                foreach (Leilao s in AvailableAuctions)
                {
                    s.Temporizador = getTimeLeft(s.DataEncerramento);
                    if(s.Temporizador.TotalDays > 0)
                    {
                        if (s.Temporizador.TotalDays > 1 && s.Temporizador.TotalDays < 2)
                            s.TempoRestante = string.Format("{0} Dia", (int)s.Temporizador.TotalDays);
                        else
                        {
                            s.TempoRestante = string.Format("{0} Dias", (int)s.Temporizador.TotalDays);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s.TempoRestante = string.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}s", (int)s.Temporizador.TotalHours, s.Temporizador.Minutes, s.Temporizador.Seconds);
                    }
                    s.OnPropertyChanged("TempoRestante");
                }
                //OnPropertyChanged("AvailableAuctions");
                //OnPropertyChanged("ActivatedAuctions");
            });
        }
```

Comment: XF versions and did you recently update it?

Comment: XF 3.4.0 have not recently updated it.

Comment: If you are using syncfusion ListView then you should get in touch with sync fusion they can help you with this issue in a better way than us

Comment: I've just tried and the bug happens with regular listview as well

Comment: Then you might want to check your code because there must be something wrong in there which is causing this and not the ListView, quite honestly if you ask me both images look the same to me

Comment: Can you provide the code in contentPage?

Comment: @G.hakim the text on the bottom image has been cut even though the layoutsizes stay the same

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT just added the codebehind plus the reffered methods on the viewModel

CallsWrapper.GetUser(); gets user data from server and leilaoDtoDataStore.GetItemsAsync(); gets the data i need for the listviews

Comment: @AndreMotta Maybe you have uploaded the wrong images take a look.

Comment: @G.hakim please read what is written in the second item of the list view for both items. It is bound to the object and the properties on the object have not changed. Verified on a breakpoint

Comment: @AndreMotta Are you using Fast Renderers?

Comment: I am not using fast renderers!